# Regular expression to limit number of characters to 10

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) that will only allow lowercase letters and up to 10 characters. What I have so far looks like this:

```
pattern: /^[a-z]{0,10}+$/
```

This does not work or compile. I had a working one that would just allow lowercase letters which was this:

```
pattern: /^[a-z]+$/
```

But I need to limit the number of characters to 10.

Comment: The {} and the + do the same thing (counting), thus they are redundant, hence the error.

Comment: You should drop the '+' from /^[a-z]{0,10}+$/. It should be /^[a-z]{0,10}$/

Comment: Note that pattern `^[a-z]{0,10}+$` compiles on some languages and some of the notable ones are Java, Perl (5.10+), PHP, Ruby (1.9+). See [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) for more detail.

Comment: See also universal solution via lookahead: [Restricting Character length in Regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32477182/restricting-character-length-in-regular-expression)

Comment: @Jerry it works in Python & PHP but not in JS, [DEMO](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/94f982dc2703).

Comment: @AmineKOUIS Yes, if you read the article I linked, that notation is not possible on Javascript because of how regex is implemented there... Javascript has limited regex implementation compared to a lot of other implementations.

Answer (score 508):

You can use curly braces to control the number of occurrences. For example, this means 0 to 10:

```
/^[a-z]{0,10}$/
```

The options are:

- {3} Exactly 3 occurrences;
- {6,} At least 6 occurrences;
- {,4} At most 4 occurrences;
- {2,5} 2 to 5 occurrences.

See the [regular expression reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).

Your expression had a + after the closing curly brace, hence the error.

Comment: In chrome dev tools with ember I had to ommit the beginning `^` to property match ONLY requests with a name like `1234` or `5678`, and I had to include the $ sign

Comment: Note: be sure not to add a space between `,` and `10` (`{0, 10}` will not work).

Comment: I raised a similar question (chars and digits, limited to 6), https://stackoverflow.com/q/76370865/10655742, the question was answered by using the boundery flag \b so you need \b[a-z]{0,10}\b, the suggestion(s) with `^` and `$` did not work for me

Answer (score 13):

`/^[a-z]{0,10}$/` should work. `/^[a-z]{1,10}$/` if you want to match at least one character, like `/^[a-z]+$/` does.

Answer (score 11):

It might be beneficial to add greedy matching to the end of the string, so you can accept strings > than 10 and the regex will only return up to the first 10 chars. `/^[a-z0-9]{0,10}$?/`

Answer (score 10):

```
grep '^[0-9]\{1,16\}' | wc -l
```

Gives the counts with exact match count with limit

Answer (score 9):

It very much depend on the program you're using. Different programs ([Emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs), [vi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi), [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed), and [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl)) use slightly different regular expressions. In this case, I'd say that in the first pattern, the last "+" should be removed.

Answer (score 8):

```
pattern: /[\w\W]{1,10}/g
```

I used this expression for my case, it includes all the characters available in the text.

Comment: This allows for whitespace which was not asked for.