# Regular Expressions match exactly 7 or 9 digits

Tags: regex

My reg ex skills are almost zero and I am trying to match a field to have exactly 7 or 9 numbers (not between 7 or 9 so no 8 numbers is not valid).

I have tried (don't laugh)

```
/^([0-9]{7} | [0-9]{9})
```

and

```
/^([0-9]{7 | 9})
```

if someone could help and explain the answer that would be much appreciated.

I assume (maybe incorrectly) that is does not matter what (programming) language I am using

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
/^\d{7}(?:\d{2})?$/
```

`\d` is modern regex shorthand for `[0-9]`, using `(?:` prevents [a group capture](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) you don't want or need from happening.

Comment: old answer, I know, but why wouldn't this work?
`/^\d{7}(\d{2})?$/`
I understand it would create a group capture - but does that matter in this instance?  I wonder if the reason is memory related?  Be gentle - regex is not my forté.

Comment: @calipoop: it will work fine, it's just a poor habit to request behavior (group capture) that you don't need.

Comment: This answer would not catch 7 zeros like 0000000

Comment: @SaniYusuf: Of course it does.  Maybe try it first.  Why did you think that?

Comment: I should have clarified. It won't catch on an input where type is number since 00000 still evaluates as 0. Changing to type text solved it.

Answer (score 10):

Your first approach works. Just leave out the blanks, add a `$` to match the string end and the trailing slash delimiter. You also could replace `[0-9]` with the shortcut `\d`:

```
/^(\d{7}|\d{9})$/
```

Answer (score 6):

Seven or nine digits is seven digits optionally followed by two more digits:

```
[0-9]{7}([0-9]{2})?
```

Comment: You have to anchor the expression.

Comment: Depends on where they use it. Not for Java's `Pattern.matches()` for example.

Answer (score 3):

use this regex `^\d{7}(\d{2})?$`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably easier done in the programming lanuage that you're using, but it can be achieved in regex as well. Take a look at this link : [Regular expression to limit number of characters to 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649435/regular-expression-to-limit-number-of-characters-to-10)

Answer (score 0):

Your first one will work if you just remove the spaces (and optionnaly the parenthesis).