# 7 or 10 digits input validation using javascript regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want user to type either 7 digits number or 10 digits number in a textbox.

**My code:**

```
var numberfilter = /^([0-9]{7})|([0-9]{10})$/;
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["number_field"].value;
if(numberfilter.test(x)==true)
    alert("Valid");
else if(numberfilter.test(x)==false)
    alert("Invalid");
```

The above regular expression is showing "valid" for 7 or more digits also. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `|` operator applies to the whole expressions on the left and right side not just the group in brackets, unless you put it inside a group. So your expression is basically:

`^([0-9]{7})` or `([0-9]{10})$`

what you need is duplicate the `^$` anchors on both sides of `|`:

`^([0-9]{7})$|(^[0-9]{10})$`

or

group the whole thing apart from anchors:

`^(([0-9]{7})|([0-9]{10}))$`

EDIT: The above explains where you went wrong, but the solution is not the best one. See the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797897/regular-expressions-match-exactly-7-or-9-digits) in comment for the slicker solution:

`^(\d{7})(\d{3})?$`

Comment: Thank for explaining and giving the solution.

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO**

```js
var numberfilter = /^\d{7}(?:\d{3})?$/;
var x='6666666666';
var y='66666666';
var z='6666666';
test(x);
test(y);
test(z);
function test(x){
 if(numberfilter.test(x)==true)
    console.log(x+" Valid");
 else if(numberfilter.test(x)==false)
    console.log(x+" Invalid");
}
```

Here is Regex `/^\d{7}(?:\d{3})?$/` checks for first 7 digit with [(?:](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#non-capturing-groups-with) capturing group for next 3 digit

Answer (score 0):

try regex

`/^([0-9]{7})$|^([0-9]{10})$/` (whole word length is 7 or whole word length is 10)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex actually says "Match if the first 7 characters are numbers OR if the last 10 characters are numbers".

This is because you forgot to place the anchors on both ends of the conditionals. Try something like this.

```
^([0-9]{7})$|^([0-9]{10})$
```

You can see it work [here](http://regexr.com/3gcqi).