# Check POST with preg_match

Tags: php, forms, preg-match

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression to limit number of characters to 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649435/regular-expression-to-limit-number-of-characters-to-10)

I retrieve a POST to a standard form and I need to test two things:

- The value must be 40 characters
- The value must contain only letters and numbers

I think it is possible to do this with preg_match, but I do not know how.

Comment: have you tried just doing a google search for "php form validation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the global $_POST you have all your posted data on the http request.

then:

```
$myvar = $_POST['your_posted_variable_here'];

$result = preg_match('/^([\w\d]){40}$/i', $myvar);
```

$result will be true if your posted data only contains letters and digits and is 40 characters  long, otherwise will be false.

Answer (score 0):

For *exactly* 40 characters:

`^[a-zA-Z0-9]{40}$`

For *at least* 40 characters:

`^[a-zA-Z0-9]{40,}$`

Comment: ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{40}[a-zA-Z0-9]*$ that's rediculous... you should use ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{40,}$ the DRY principle still applies to regex.

Comment: You're right, I forgot about openended brackets.

Comment: Easily done when theres so many meta characters, etc ;)

Comment: I wonder if there's a performance difference between the two. Obviously it's not going to make a noticeable difference on the scale of PHP regex, but does separating out the fixed part change anything?

Comment: what do you mean "seperating out the fixed" part? In general, if you can get away with NOT using regex, then do it. The other string handling functions like substr strpos etc are much much faster than regex.

Comment: Sure, of course non-regex is faster. I meant between my original answer and what you corrected it to - does it make a difference one way or the other to search for two sections of a pattern rather than one, given that one is of fixed rather than variable length? Regex is generally slower with more complicated patterns, of course, but I'm curious about this particular case.

Comment: fixed length is usually faster in anything relating to computers ;) this is no exception.

Comment: Obviously, but there's still a variable-length section to be taken care of afterwards.

Comment: Yeahhhh, i'm just confused now >< haha. Time to re-read the comments. "^[a-zA-Z0-9]{40}[a-zA-Z0-9]*$" VS "^[a-zA-Z0-9]{40,}$"... hmmm... i would say the first is just a tad faster because the engine won't have to discard the first sub pattern to then load a new one (the [...]* part). Just an educated guess though :)

Answer (score 0):

**Information on preg_match**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

```
if (preg_match("@^[a-z0-9]{40}$@mis", $_POST['username'])) {
    print 'matched';
}
```

Comment: Why the `m` and `s` flags? Do they matter?

Comment: @SalmanA `m` does matter, otherwise it would match inputs where _any_ line has exactly 40 characters, all alphanumeric

Comment: @SalmanA Actually, `m` does the opposite than I claimed (apology). If multiline is on, `^` and `$` _do_ match line breaks (which isn't desired here): http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html

Comment: According to the same documentation, `s` = "dot matches all", which doesn't have an effect in this regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the length of the string using strlen() first, then if it satisfies the desired length, go forth with the checking of alpha numerics.

But General has the right idea...

Here's another way:

```
preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z_]{40,}$/", $_POST["something"])
```

This is alpha numeric, and checks for at least 40 characters, but will accept more. The missing value after the comma means that it can be of any value equal or bigger than 40.

Answer (score 0):

PHP provides a function for checking alphanumeric characters [ctype_alnum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php) and [strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) to check the length of a string so using both functions you can validate it

```
$yourInput=$_POST['yourInput'];
if(ctype_alnum($yourInput) && strlen($strlen)==40)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: This approach has more simplicity than using a regex, but LESS PERFORMANCE.

Comment: @slash28cu, `LESS PERFORMANCE` such as ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera I don't think performance is top-priority here, but: `strlen` may have to iterate the whole string to get its length, while a regex only has to read the first 40 characters to find the string is longer.

Comment: @Sheikh Heera . From php manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php#94989

Comment: @Sheikh Heera .Also is a more elegant way to use regex, also notice that your if have to conditions to evaluate rather than just a simple regex.

Comment: @slash28cu not a mention of performance in the linked document.

Comment: @slash28cu, sounds logical but like you said performance is not top-priority here so I think it's the simplest one.

Comment: GUYS, Read well. is in there.                                 """ ctype_alnum() is a godsend for quick and easy username/data filtering when used in conjunction with str_replace(). 

Let's say your usernames have dash(-) and underscore(_) allowable and alphanumeric digits as well. 

Instead of a regex you can trade a bit of performance for simplicity.""" This has been textual from the link.

Comment: @slash28cu: do you have an actual benchmark and result to support your argument?

Comment: @slash28cu didn't notice, sorry. Still an unsourced claim by the commenter.

Comment: @Sheik Heera . i know that every problem has multiple solutions, and if somebody doesn't know how to write this EXTREMELY simple regex can use this approach, otherwise i think regex are a very elegant solution and in this case is as simple as your answer.

Comment: @Salman. I don't think that you need a benchmarking tool just to realize that even if in this case is not significative to the app, A regex have by far much better perfomance than multiple string manipulation functions inside an if statement.

Comment: @slash28cu, I didn't say you are wrong and yes everyone has unique thoughts so basically we have different view and we act like so.

Comment: @SheikhHeera Of course. I am not saying you are wrong either , i am just highlighting a performance comparison between string manipulation functions and a regex. But of course we all have different approaches.