# Parse decimal from textblock (string) and convert to hexidecimal

Tags: c#, parsing, hex, xbox360

Okay so lets say I input this in to a rich textbox:

```
private void noRecoilOn()
{
    this.Jtag.WriteUInt32(2200480928u, 1024u);
}
private void noRecoilOff()
{
    this.Jtag.WriteUInt32(2200480928u, 0u);
}
```

I want to be able to parse out the decimals and convert it to Hexadecimal like so:

```
private void noRecoilOn()
{
    this.Jtag.WriteUInt32(0x8328ACA0, 0x400);
}
private void noRecoilOff()
{
    this.Jtag.WriteUInt32(0x8328ACA0, 0x0);
}
```

This is just a quick example but the real things I will be converting will be whole blocks of code with many different decimals that need to be converted, not just "2200480928u".

How would I go about doing this. I have no idea

Comment: do you mean display as hex?

Comment: so it takes the input, with the decimals, then in another richtextbox, displays the same code but with hexadecimals instead of decimals

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at [How to: Convert Between Hexadecimal Strings and Numeric Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx)

In addition the `ToString()` has a [format to write to Hex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and `UInt32.Parse` can be [provided an IFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/41810tes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
uint num = 2200480928u;

// Converts the uint to a hex string
string hex = num.ToString("X");


// Convert the hex string back to the number
uint number = UInt32.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Comment: I will try this when i get home. The only other question I have would be how can I parse the uint out of the block of code I an passing through the input?

Comment: @user2692560 You would need to find an appropriate pattern to search for and replace.  Possibly a Regex expression like *"[0-9]+u"*. But that makes an assumption that all numbers followed by a u should be changed.

Comment: This pattern works well for what I need but is there a way to edit it so it will only replace uints that are a certain length? For example only replace uints that are 7 chars long

Comment: *"[0-9]{7}u"* would look for exactly 7 numbers followed by a u and  "*[0-9]{7,}u"* would look for at least 7 numbers followed by a u. [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649435/regular-expression-to-limit-number-of-characters-to-10)