# Java Regex specify length

Tags: java, regex

Please find below the regex I am using for validating an email address. This is working fine.

```
^[-!#$%&\\'*+\\\\./<MORE_REGEX_HERE>^_`a-z{|}~]+$
```

Now I want to add a length check in this regex for example the email address can be of max length 60. So I tried something like below

```
^([-!#$%&\\'*+\\\\./<MORE_REGEX_HERE>^_`a-z{|}~]+){1,60}$
```

But its not working. Any thoughts?

Comment: In addition to your original regex, you could check for the length `^.{,60}$`.

Comment: why didnt just specify your input `maxlength='60'`? :D

Comment: @RafaEl - You mean in UI right that is already there but I want to re verify in backend.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649435/regular-expression-to-limit-number-of-characters-to-10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey you can find the below solution if it works:-

It might be so that you are having multiple matching strings within a single -

^[-!#$%&\'*+\\.]+[^_`a-z{|}~]+$

in such cases you cannot use ^[-!#$%&\'*+\\.]+[^_`a-z{|}~]{1,60}$

to match the whole string but it matches only the second part of the string in such cases you need to use the below regex:  -

```
[^[-!#$%&\\'*+\\\\.]+[<MORE_REGEX_HERE>^_`a-z{|}~]+$]{1,60}
```

Try it should work now.

Comment: Did you really try it?

Comment: Yes I did using a different regex and number.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a valid way of validating emails try this:
[Good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204680/java-regex-email/13013056#13013056)

Using {n,m} matches n(minimum inclusive) to m (maximum inclusive) characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertion:

```
^(?=[-!#$%&\\'*+\\\\./<MORE_REGEX_HERE>^_`a-z{|}~]+).{1,60}$
```