# Limit chars occurrences with regex

Tags: regex

I'm using for exmaple this simple regex:

`([A-Za-z0-9!@#]*)`

I want to limit the chars `!`, `@` and `#`, while each of them can appear up to 5 times in the whole string.

Valid strings will be: `t!!!sd###ui##pp!@`, `!@#II#@!00!!` etc.

Not valid strings will be: `3!222@34@#@@#@@@!`, `!@!@!@!@!@!A`

Is it possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649435/regular-expression-to-limit-number-of-characters-to-10

Comment: @adifire That not what I'm looking for.

Comment: What regex flavour are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern:

```
^(?!(?:[^!]*!){6})(?!(?:[^@]*@){6})(?!(?:[^#]*#){6})[A-Za-z0-9!@#]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use lookahead for this. Use this regex:

```
^(?!(.*?!){6})(?!(.*?#){6})(?!(.*?@){6})[A-Za-z0-9!@#]+$
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/cR9yH9

Comment: `a@sd@@@@!` returns false, while it should be true.

Comment: Let me test and revert back.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Thanks for your comment. I had a typo (closing bracket misplaced). Corrected now, it should work now.