# How to create a regular expression to accept only upto 12 digits?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

How to create a regular expression to accept only upto 12 digits? 
Many Thanks

Comment: Read some regex tutorial, shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1649441/362536

Answer (score 3):

```
/^\d{0,12}$/
```

... which breaks down as ...

```
/      # start regex
^      # anchor to start of string
\d     # 0-9
{0,12} # 0-12 times
$      # anchor end of string
/      # end regex
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:^|[^0-9])([0-9]{1,12})(?![0-9])
```

I have divided problem to 3 part according to answers.

1. Problem want to does not start with digit

**(?:^|[^0-9])** means that starts with non digit character or does not start with any character

2. Problem want to consume 12 digit:

**[0-9]** means that we want to consume just digits

**{1,12}** means that we want to consume up to 12 character

3. Problem want to does not consume these 12 digit if 13rd character is digit also.

**?** means that look but does not consume

**![0-9]** means that this character could be everything except digit.

Comment: If for example, a string contains only 13 digits followed by an other character that is not a digit, your pattern will match too, not at the position 0 but at the position 1. If the string contains only 12 digits the pattern will fail too since there isn't a 13th character to make `(?=[^0-9])` to succeed.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yes I will see that point. I will update my answer

Comment: Take care to refresh the page since I have edited my comment several times.

Comment: As an aside, whatever what you answer, it's basically a crappy question (too broad, no effort... === Off topic), so don't bother about it.

Comment: When you want to look around in javascript (that doesn't support lookbehind), you can ends your pattern with a negative lookahead (like `(?![0-9])` that is equivalent to `(?=[^0-9]|$)`) and you need to start with an alternation like that: `(?:^|[^0-9])`. To extract the twelve digits, the only way is to use a capture group.

Comment: Yes I have looked up for lookbehind implementation in javascript. But have not implemented yet. Your start alternation works with consuming 1 character. Because of that if you want to operation with that you should make group for first character that is not digit. Anyway i think we will find most correct answer :)

Comment: Perhaps, but since nobody knows if he is looking for a pattern that searches for twelve digits in a text or if he's looking for a pattern that validates only twelve digits strings, it remains too broad.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte yes because of the crappy question.