# regex match password requirements

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use a regex to match a set of password requirements. They are:

- Needs to 8-15 characters
- One uppercase letter
- One lowercase letter
- One number

I'm using https://regexr.com/ to try to build it.

The first attempt:

```
/([A-Z])([a-z])([0-9])({8,15})+/g
```

But in the console of the web app this throws:

[image]

But in this answer, [Regular expression to limit number of characters to 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649435/regular-expression-to-limit-number-of-characters-to-10) they go:

```
/^[a-z]{0,10}$/
```

So I tried to roll with this idea:

```
/[A-Z][a-z][0-9]{8,15}/g
```

And the errors clear but it is always false. Why?

Below is a sample. The alert should be true because it contains all the requirements.

```js
function checkPass() {
  var regex = /[A-Z][a-z][0-9]{8,15}/g;
  var string = "G00dPassword1234"
  var isItGood = regex.test(string);
  alert(isItGood)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="checkPass()">test</button>
```

Why is my test always false?

Comment: `^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{8,15}$` or `^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]{8,15}$`

Comment: The regex you got means one uppercase A-Z, followed by one lowercase a-z, followed by 8 to 15 times a digit. See [this](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5BA-Z%5D%5Ba-z%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B8%2C15%7D) for a visualization.