# How do you find all instances of a substring, followed by a certain number of dynamic characters?

Tags: python

I'm trying to find all instances of a specific substring(a!b2 as an example) and return them with the 4 characters that follow after the substring match. These 4 following characters are always dynamic and can be any letter/digit/symbol.

I've tried searching, but it seems like the similar questions that are asked are requesting help with certain characters that can easily split a substring, but since the characters I'm looking for are dynamic, I'm not sure how to write the regex.

Comment: Read about the `re` module in `python`. I could probably tell more if you give an example.

Comment: possible solution: `[substring + i[:4] for i in string.split(substring)[1:]]`, would help to have an expected input/output though

Comment: The special regex character "." can match any character. Does that help?

Comment: Can you give an example so we can understand more ?

Answer (score 1):

When using regex, you can use "." to dynamically match any character. Use `{number}` to specify how many characters to match, and use parentheses as in `(.{number})` to specify that the match should be captured for later use.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "a!b2foobar a!b2bazqux a!b2spam and eggs"
>>> print(re.findall("a!b2(.{4})", s))
['foob', 'bazq', 'spam']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only looking for how to grab the following 4 characters using *Regex*, what you are probably looking to use is the curly brace indicator for quantity to match: '{}'.

They go into more detail in the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649435/regular-expression-to-limit-number-of-characters-to-10), but essentially you would do `[a-Z][0-9]{X,Y}` or `(.{X,Y})`, where X to Y is the number of characters you're looking for (in your case, you would only need `{4}`).

---

A more *Pythonic* way to solve this problem would be to make use of string slicing, and the index function however.

Eg. given an input_string, when you find the substring at index i using [index](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/index), then you could use `input_string[i+len(sub_str):i+len(sub_str)+4]` to grab those special characters.

As an example,

```
input_string = 'abcdefg'
sub_str = 'abcd'
found_index = input_string.index(sub_str)
start_index = found_index + len(sub_str)
symbol = input_string[start_index: start_index + 4]
```

> Outputs (to show it works with <4 as well): efg

Index also allows you to give start and end indexes for the search, so you could also use it in a loop if you wanted to find it for every sub string, with the start of the search index being the previous found index + 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
print (re.search(r'a!b2(.{4})')).group(1))
```

`.{4}` matches any 4 characters except `special characters`.
`group(0)` is the complete match of the searched string. You can read about group `id` [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.Pattern.groupindex).